# Execution of Form actions in a Frameset with JSP

Tags: forms, jsp, action, frames

I have a webapp that uses a frameset.

p.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Übersicht</title>
</head>
<frameset border="2" frameborder="1" framespacing="0" cols= "850,*">
<frame  src="/servlets/servlet/P" name="left">
    <frameset border="2" frameborder="1" framespacing="0" rows="25%,*">
        <frame src="right-top.html" name="right-top">
        <frame src="nothing.html" name="right-bottom">
    </frameset>
</frameset>
</html>
```

right-top.html:

```
<HTML>
<TITLE>Info</TITLE>
<HEAD>
</HEAD>
<p><h1>right-top</h1></p>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

nothing.html:

```
<HTML>
<TITLE>Nothing</TITLE>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#ffffff" ONLOAD="nothing">
<HEAD>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</HEAD>
<SCRIPT>
<!--

function nothing(ev) {
   return true
}
//-->
</SCRIPT>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

The left frame is filled by a JSP (servlet running in Tomcat) with some FORMs and buttons with actions:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class P extends HttpServlet {

 public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException {
  response.setContentType("Text/html");
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

  out.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html   lang=\"de\">");

  out.println("<head>");
  out.println("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-type\" content=\"text/html;  charset=utf-8\" />");
  out.println("<title>Frames Test</title>");
  out.println("</head>");
  out.println("<body>");
  out.println("<h1>Frame left</h1></body></html>");

  out.println("<form id=\"alles\" action=\"#\">" +
   "<input form=\"alles\" type=\"hidden\" name=\"erl\" value=\"true\"/>" +
   "<button target=\"left\" type=\"submit\" form=\"alles\">" +
   "Get SystemTimeAndDate</button></form><form id=\"update\" " +
   "target=\"right-top\" action=\"/servlets/servlet/U\">" +
   "<button type=\"submit\" form=\"update\">" +
   "SVN-Update</button></form></div>");

  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
  out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));

 }
}
```

I added the printing of date and time to see when the action is performed.
The action for the upper right frame is in the following JSP:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.lang.Runtime;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

/*
 * This is a simple example of an HTTP Servlet.  It responds to the GET
 * and HEAD methods of the HTTP protocol.
 */
public class U extends HttpServlet
{ 
        public void doPost (HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
                throws ServletException, IOException
            {
                //value chosen to limit denial of service
                if (req.getContentLength() > 8*1024) {
                    res.setContentType("text/html");
                    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
                    out.println("<html>\n");
            out.println("<title>Too big</title>");
                    out.println("<body><h1>Error - content length &gt;8k not allowed"
);
                    out.println("</h1></body></html>");
                } else {
                    doGet(req, res);
                }
            }

    /**
     * Handle the GET and HEAD methods by building a simple web page.
     * HEAD is just like GET, except that the server returns only the
     * headers (including content length) not the body we write.
     */
    public void doGet (HttpServletRequest request,
                       HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException
        {
            Runtime runner= Runtime.getRuntime();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String commandline=request.getRequestURI();
            String cmd;
            response.setContentType("text/html");
        out.println("<html><body><pre>");
            out.flush();

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        out.println( sdf.format(cal.getTime()) );    
        out.close();
          }
}
```

Now things don't work as I want them to do. First off: When I load the fameset freshly into the browser (open a new tab and enter the URL), the left frame is filled with the two buttons and date is printed as the code prescribes. Also the right-top frame prints its src, name "right-top" as in right-top.html. Doing the frame reload repeatedly works fine as expected.

When I then klick the button "GetSystemTimeAndDate", the time and date are updated as expected in the left frame. But clicking the button a second time results in no action being performed.

But when I klick SVN-Update the getdate.bat is executed and the original frame src is overwritten. And so it does on every klick.

The other thing I don't understand is, why the action for SVN-Update is already executed when I just reload the frameset. One can see this with the  time being updated in the right top frame.

So in sum:

1. Why does the action fire on every frame reload once the SVN-Update button has been clicked once?
2. Why does button GetSystemTimeAndDate only fire once after a fresh frameload?

Comment: Is there any specific reason you're deliberatley making your code server and platform specific by requiring a bat file to get the date and time when java has built in functions for it?

Comment: Thanks for the critics. Indeed the OS-specific portion (process execution of a .BAT) was unnecessary. I removed it.